# How to process files using Spark Structured Streaming chunk by chunk?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am treating a large amount of files, and I want to treat these files chunk by chunk, let's say that during each batch, I want to treat each 50 files separately.

How can I do it using Spark Structured Streaming ?

I have seen that Jacek Laskowski (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1305344/jacek-laskowski) said in a similar question ([Spark to process rdd chunk by chunk from json files and post to Kafka topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44063349/spark-to-process-rdd-chunk-by-chunk-from-json-files-and-post-to-kafka-topic)) that it was possible using the Spark Structured Streaming, but I can't find any examples about it.

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If using File Source:

maxFilesPerTrigger: maximum number of new files to be considered in every trigger (default: no max)

```
spark
  .readStream
  .format("json")
  .path("/path/to/files")
  .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 50)
  .load
```

If using a Kafka Source it would be similar but with the `maxOffsetsPerTrigger` option.

Comment: In case when you are using `maxFilesPerTrigger` then you have to also specify the `checkpointLocation` in the `writeStream.option`